# Dynamic Image Loading in Android Offline HTML5 app using Sencha

Tags: android, html, image, extjs, assets

Good day folks. 
I am stuck with a strange problem and after lots of googling I couldn't find the solution/answer

I am creating and Sencha +cordova app for android.

It simply display 10 images in loop. 
my code works fine on Chrome browser in desktop. 
It fails On android 4.4.2 device when I install as APK.
Please help to fix the code for android.

```
    init: function () {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            //console.log('init');
            if(Ext.os.name == 'Android')
                baseurl = baseAndroidUrl;
            else 
                baseurl = baseDesktopUrl;

                //alert('baseurl ' + baseurl);
        }

    var baseurl;
    var baseAndroidUrl = 'file:///android_asset/www/resources/resources/images/';
    var baseDesktopUrl = '/resources/resources/images/';
    var imageArray = 
            ['page00.jpg', 
            'page01.jpg',
            'page02.jpg',
            'page03.jpg',
            'page04.jpg',
            'page05.jpg',
            'page06.jpg',
            'page07.jpg',
            'page08.jpg',
            'page09.jpg',
            'page10.jpg'];

    var counter = 0; 
    -----------------------------------------------
    onPrePageCommand: function () {

            console.log('onPrePageCommand');

             if( counter === 0 )
            return ;
            counter--;
            // Folloing dynamic updation doesn't work in android , works perfectly on desktop 
            Ext.getCmp('pageID').setSrc(baseurl+imageArray[counter]);
                     //Ext.getCmp('pageID ').doLayout();

        },
        onNextPageCommand: function () {

            console.log('onNextPageCommand');
            if( counter === imageArray.length-1 )
            return ;
            counter++;
            Ext.getCmp('pageID').setSrc(baseurl+imageArray[counter]);


        },
    ------------------------------------------
    //initial view : work perfect for both Desktop browser and APK 
    {
                xtype: 'image',
                src:'resources/images/Page00.jpg',
                id:'pageID',
                mode:'image'
                height:'100%',
                width:'100%'
            }
    --------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Framework for that like http://wowslider.com/ this worked great for me the last time. You can also scroll the images with your fingers (swipe them).